# sympy solve not giving correct result

Tags: python, sympy

refer to this [desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9c1bubnpof), I try to solve the x-intercepts by:

```py
import sympy as sym
print(sym.solve('1.0*x**3 - 3.0*x**2 - 25.0*x + 25.0'))
# [-4.25542010777727 - 0.e-22*I, 0.928558406041155 + 0.e-20*I, 6.32686170173611 - 0.e-21*I]
```

The expected output is a list of float values. beside, I need to use this method to find roots of a lot of different polynomials with respect to x, some of them may not have a root, I am worried that there may be some imaginary numbers generated in the future, is there a way I can reject imaginary values?

I will be so glad if someone offer some suggestion.

Comment: Why? Excluding the imaginary part (almost 0), these points are the ones where your function intersects the x axes.

Comment: @cissal, they are `Add` objects, can I convert to float values and get rid of imaginary ones?

Comment: As you can see here: [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x**3-3x**2-25x%2B25) the roots match the ones found by sympy. The imaginary part is just a rounding error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can verify from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x**3-3x**2-25x%2B25), the roots found by `sympy` are indeed the roots of your polynomial.

Likely due to the algorithm implemented by sympy, there are some floating point / rounding errors resulting in an imaginary "left-over" term. However, as you can see, it is almost equal to zero (`~ e-22`).

To just keep the real part of the solution, you could do the following

```py
import sympy as sym
res = sym.solve('1.0*x**3 - 3.0*x**2 - 25.0*x + 25.0')
res = [x.as_two_terms()[0] for x in res]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use sympy's `real_roots` function to find real roots of polynomials:

```
In [2]: p = parse_expr('1.0*x**3 - 3.0*x**2 - 25.0*x + 25.0')

In [3]: p
Out[3]: 
     3        2                
1.0⋅x  - 3.0⋅x  - 25.0⋅x + 25.0

In [4]: real_roots(p)
Out[4]: 
⎡       ⎛ 3      2               ⎞         ⎛ 3      2               ⎞         ⎛ 3      2               ⎞⎤
⎣CRootOf⎝x  - 3⋅x  - 25⋅x + 25, 0⎠, CRootOf⎝x  - 3⋅x  - 25⋅x + 25, 1⎠, CRootOf⎝x  - 3⋅x  - 25⋅x + 25, 2⎠⎦

In [5]: p = parse_expr('1.0*x**3 - 3.0*x**2 - 25.0*x + 25.0')

In [6]: real_roots(p)
Out[6]: 
⎡       ⎛ 3      2               ⎞         ⎛ 3      2               ⎞         ⎛ 3      2               ⎞⎤
⎣CRootOf⎝x  - 3⋅x  - 25⋅x + 25, 0⎠, CRootOf⎝x  - 3⋅x  - 25⋅x + 25, 1⎠, CRootOf⎝x  - 3⋅x  - 25⋅x + 25, 2⎠⎦

In [7]: [r.n() for r in real_roots(p)]
Out[7]: [-4.25542010777727, 0.928558406041155, 6.32686170173611]
```

The algorithm in `real_roots` can explicitly determine that the roots are real whereas solve is numerically evaluating the cubic formula which can give small imaginary parts from rounding error in the case of casus irreducibilus:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

Answer (score 1):

The results are fine, you just need to read about `e`.
To check my words just use this

```
import sympy as sym
res = sym.solve('1.0*x**3 - 3.0*x**2 - 25.0*x + 25.0')
for i in res:
    print(round(i, 2))
```

UPD:
You can map it

```
import sympy as sym
res = list(map(lambda e: round(e, 2), sym.solve('1.0*x**3 - 3.0*x**2 - 25.0*x + 25.0')))
print(res)
```

UPD2:

```
import sympy as sym
roots = sym.solve('1.0*x**3 - 3.0*x**2 - 25.0*x + 25.0')
result = [sym.re(i) for i in roots if round(sym.im(i), 3) < 0.001]
```

Comment: or you can map it

Comment: rounding loses the precision on the real part of the number, so it is not really an appropriate technique for getting rid of the imaginary part

Comment: furthermore, your code doesn't even work, since the `Add` type doesnt have a `round` method...