# sympy solve function gives wrong result

Tags: python, sympy

according to this graph: [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qop29hevlo)

```py
print(solve('x**2 + x - 1/x'))
# [-1/3 + (-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(69)/18 + 25/54)**(1/3) + 1/(9*(-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(69)/18 + 25/54)**(1/3)), -1/3 + 1/(9*(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(69)/18 + 25/54)**(1/3)) + (-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(69)/18 + 25/54)**(1/3), -1/3 + 1/(9*(sqrt(69)/18 + 25/54)**(1/3)) + (sqrt(69)/18 + 25/54)**(1/3)]
```

I was expecting `[0.755, 0.57]`, but, I got something I cannot use in my future program. **I desire to get a list of floats as result**, so refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67636112/11645617), I did following, but I got some even more weird:

```py
def solver(solved, rit=3):
    res = []
    for val in solved:
        if isinstance(val, core.numbers.Add):
            flt = val.as_two_terms()[0]
            flt = round(flt, rit)
        else:
            flt = round(val, rit)
        if not isinstance(flt, core.numbers.Add):
            res.append(flt)
    return res

print(solver(solve('x**2 + x - 1/x')))
# [-0.333, -0.333, -0.333]
```

Now I am really disappointed with sympy, I wonder if there is an accurate way to get a list of floats as result, or I will code my own gradient descent algorithm to find the roots and intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sym.solve` solves an equation for the independent variable. If you provide an expression, it'll assume the equation `sym.Eq(expr, 0)`. But this only gives you the x values. You have to substitute said solutions to find the y value.

Your equation has 3 solutions. A conjugate pair of complex solutions and a real one. The latter is where your two graphs meet.

```
import sympy as sym

x = sym.Symbol('x')
# better to represent it like the equation it is
eq = sym.Eq(x**2, 1/x - x)
sol = sym.solve(eq)

for s in sol:
    if s.is_real:
        s = s.evalf()
        print(s, eq.lhs.subs({x: s}))   # eq.rhs works too
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of things you can do to get the solution. If you know the approximate root location and you want a numerical answer, `nsolve` is simplest since it has no requirements on the type of expression:

```
>>> from sympy import nsolve, symbols
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> eq = x**2 + x - 1/x
>>> nsolve(eq, 1)
0.754877666246693
```

You can try a guess near 0.57 but it will go to the same solution. So is there really a second real roots? You can't use `real_roots` on this expression because it isn't in polynomial form. But if you split it into numerator and denominator you can check for the roots of the numerator:

```
>>> n, d = eq.as_numer_denom()
>>> from sympy import real_roots
>>> real_roots(n)
[CRootOf(x**3 + x**2 - 1, 0)]
```

So there is only one real root for that expression, the one that `nroots` gave you.

Note: the answer that solve gives is an exact solution to the cubic equation and it can't figure out definitively which ones are a solution to the equation so it returns all three. If you evaluate them you will find that only one of them is real. But since you don't need the symbolic solution, just stick to `nroots`.